# What is val() for in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to learn codeigniter and jquery. There is always a val() that nobody explains. What is it for?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When it comes to jQuery, it is all [in the documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/val).

Essentially, the `val` function is to set or get the value of an element.

If you have an input field, like so:

```
<input name='my_field' id='my_field' value='Hello World'>
```

Then you can do this to get the value of the field:

```
var value = $('#my_field').val();
```

Or do this to *set* the value of the field:

```
$('#my_field').val('My new value');
```

Comment: He linked to the specific page.

Comment: see the link on the first line of the answer